# Value of macro variable as length of another variable?

Tags: macros, sas, variable-length

I am new to SAS and didn't find an answer to my question. Maybe this community would/could be so Kind to help me.

Is it possible to define the value of a macro variable as the length of another variable? I do know that the value of a macro is character, but is there a way to do is?

My Problem is this: I want to check my variable for the longest value and set the length of the longest value as a new length for the variable. Therefore I used this program:

```
proc sql;

select max(length(variable))

into: length_variable

from dm_comp;
quit;

%put length_variable;
```

Now I have the value as character in my macro, but I don't know how to use this macro to set a new length. Is it even possible to do this way? If not, do you have an idea how to do it better? Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a Data Step to redefine the variable and populate it from the old Data Set.

```
/*Data with variable length 10, only need 2*/
data temp;
length x $ 10;
x="1";
output;
x="11";
output;
run;

proc sql noprint;
select max(length(x))
    into: length_variable
from temp;
quit;

/*Puts 2 as expected*/
%put &length_variable;

/*First define the variable and the new length,
  Then "set" the Data step - rename the old variable.
  Set the new variable to the old one (I strip whitespace here)*/
data temp(drop=x_old);
length x $ &length_variable;
set temp(rename=(x=x_old));
x = strip(x_old);
run;

/*CONTENTS Show us the new length*/
proc contents data=temp;
run;
```

Results

```
                  Alphabetic List of Variables and Attributes

                         #    Variable    Type    Len

                         1    x           Char      2
```

Comment: I don't think you need the rename(x=x_old) part or the assignment statement.  Just adding a length statement before the SET statement will work.  It will throw a warning about truncating the value, which you can avoid by setting system option varlenchk=nowarn;

Comment: @Quentin, you are correct.  I did it this way to avoid the WARNING in the log without having to change the system options.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. This works. Now, what if I want to put my code into a macro, if I want to use it repeatedly?  <br/>

Comment: I am very sorry, I still dont know how to edit and code properly on this Website. I wanted to create a macro like this:          %macro sql (var,dataset);  
     proc sql;  
     select max(length(&var))  
     into: l_&var  
     from &dataset;  
    quit;  
   %mend;   unfortunately, it doesn't resolve the &l_&var macro and I don't know why.

Comment: That's really a different question.  Short answer is try `&&l_&var`.  Ask another question if you need a detailed answer with "why."

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. You just need to format the new variable correctly:

```
proc sql;
    select max(length(variable))
    into: length_variable
    from dm_comp;
quit;

proc sql;
    create table dm_comp2 as select
        *, your_var as resized_var format %sysfunc(strip(&length_variable.)).
        from dm_comp;
quit;
```

Comment: Changing the format is different than changing the length.  The format effects how values will be displayed.  The length effects how they are stored.  I think you would want  `your_var as resized_var length &length_variable`